SwiftUI scrollPosition does not work with animation duration
I am a beginner to SwiftUI and I am trying to scroll to positions on the screen based on a parameter, but I want to set a duration as well because now it scrolls fast, I want to slow it down but I have tried everything i can but does not seem to work
struct NftList: View {
    var range: ClosedRange<Int>
    @State private var targetIndex: Int?
    @State private var scrollProxy: ScrollViewProxy?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(range, id: \.self) { index in
                    Image("\(index)")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                }
                .onAppear() {
                    targetIndex = range.upperBound;
                }
            }
        }
        .scrollPosition(id: $targetIndex, anchor: .center)
        .animation(.linear(duration: 0.2), value: targetIndex)
        .onChange(of: targetIndex) { oldIndex, newIndex in
            
            if newIndex == range.upperBound {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                    targetIndex = range.lowerBound
                }
            } else if newIndex == range.lowerBound {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                    targetIndex = range.upperBound
                }
            }
        }
        .rotationEffect(.radians(Double.pi * 1.96))
        .frame(height: 130)
        .scaleEffect(x: 1.08)
    }
}


I'm pretty sure you cannot control the scroll animation. What ScrollView-specific behaviour do you need? If this is just an animation in onAppear, I would initially show a HStack animating its offset, and only when the animation finishes, replace the HStack with a scroll view.

Similar to Animation is not working as expected when programatilcly scrolling to in SwiftUI, but using scrollPosition instead of a ScrollViewReader. It seems that setting a duration for the animation doesn't work.
